# What are Angular Security Risks for Implementing Restful Admin Areas?

Tags: angularjs, security, restful-authentication

I interested in implementing restful admin areas with AngularJS.
Since APIs should be stateless, i want to implement the admin area using OAuth and I'm horrible about security risks like MitM.

So what are the security risks in this case and how can fix theme?

Comment: What I normally think when wondering about security is: How massive is my app gonna be and how valuable is my data. Is it worth it? have in mind that doing something simple like de-crypt a database is a costly operation, if your data has no value is just not worth it for someone to spend resources in trying to get it. As per user "sessions" with JWT you should be covered for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should use https://jwt.io/introduction/ for stateless auth.

Helpful link 
https://auth0.com/blog/2015/03/31/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/